# Integration DWR (Direct Web Remoting) with WebSphere Portal

Tags: java, servlets, portlet, websphere-portal, dwr

what is the best way to integrate DWR (Direct Web Remoting) with WebSphere Portal? I have WebSphere Portal 7.

For the time, I have just add the jar DWR3.jar to lib folder and I have declare the DWR servlet to web.xml.

Its works good if I dit not need session or not generate content which contains links.

But if I want store data in session from DWR and retrieve without DWR, data are sometimes lost...

I have see that dwr url call :

[image]

This call does not call Portlet Servlet.

Other call in portal :

[image]

This call does call Portlet Servlet.

How sessions are shared in WebSphere portal?

Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if DWR servlet is part of same WAS of portal then both portal and DWR servlet share same session.